# Mass css :hover application

Tags: css, hover

Is there a way to apply some css to all items that have a :hover in css?

e.g. I want to apply font-weight:bold to all of the following at once.

```
.btn:hover{
  color:red;
}
.box:hover{
  color:blue;
}
.wrapper:hover{
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: use comma to separate them ? or maybe the unirversal selector `*`?

Comment: why dont you add a common class for these elements?

Comment: I'll use the universal selector thanks! Didn't know that existed.

Pedro I'm too far down the line with my project, there are very many classes that I want to change at once.

Comment: There is no way you can target elements that have a `:hover` rule specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
*:hover {
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Placing your cursor _anywhere_ in the window would make _everything_ bold. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Turnip No, it wouldn't. It would only affect the element hovered and any descendant elements that inherit `font-weight` from it.

Comment: @connexo Yes. Exactly. You hover body and every element on the page becomes bold since they are all descendants of body.

Comment: But not all inherit `font-weight`.

Comment: I only wanted to add these two attributes to every single hover. So in this case the *:hover is very useful.

transition-duration: 0.25s; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple pen for you

Apply hover to multiple classes and using attribute selectors
https://codepen.io/Sensiblemnd/pen/LJzejK

```
.wrapper:hover, .box:hover, .btn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

//example with attribute selectors

[class^='bold-']{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```